# I can't add items from JArray to comboBox

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I can't add items from JArray to comboBox.Why I can't add its? Code is like it.
      I am reading JSON and assigning a variable name of "data".And I parsing.
Then put for loop and should 'ad' datas adding in combobox.But doesnt work.What can I do?
//Sorry for bad english my age is  16

JSON CODE

```
[
    {
       "Ad": "Ali Kemal",
       "Soyad": "Sipahi",
       "Bolum": "Bilgisayar Muhendisligi",
       "Sehir": "Ankara",
       "Telefon": "05000000000"
    },
    {
       "Ad": "Neslihan",
       "Soyad": "Yağmur",
       "Bolum": "Tıp Fakültesi",
       "Sehir": "Malatya",
       "Telefon": "05000000001"
    }
]
```

Form Code

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    string data = File.ReadAllText(@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    JArray JSONParser = JArray.Parse(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < JSONParser.Count; i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(JSONParser[i]["Ad"]);
    }
}
```

What should I do? Thanks for all!

Comment: Why are you adding items when the selected item is changed? Any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the `event` `SelectedIndexChanged`  to add  element to your combobox, because your combobox is still empty and your event will not be invoked
just add your items on `Load event` of your form  or use a simple button to  load this

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to fill Combo when Combo's selected index changing

try this on form load.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"*****";
        var data = File.ReadAllText(path);
        var items = JArray.Parse(data);
        foreach (var currentItem in items)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(currentItem.Value<string>("Ad"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did it but doesnt add again. @levent